# How to make a common event bus to interact two angular4/5 app in single-spa

Tags: event-handling, single-page-application, angular5, eventemitter

I am trying to make two Angular apps and i want an event emitter to listen events commonly in between two different application with Single-spa otherwise known as MicroFrontend for multiple js framework but i am unable to find any possible solution .

Please see this link for better understanding Visit http://single-spa.surge.sh/

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone

This NgZone will act like publish and subscribe event emitter mechanism for communication from one ng2 applicaton to any other application out of angular framework .